# Dynamically sized elements inside a DIV

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV and 3 inline elements inside it.

The center element is a dynamic text for which I can't predict the width. The text is centered horizontally in the DIV. The DIV has a fixed size.

I would like the left element to be anchored to the left and flow till it reaches the text; Similarly, the right element should start just after the text and finish at the end of the DIV (right: 0 or something)

The end result is something like this:

```
111111 my-text 222222

1111 longer-text 2222
```

The sum of the width always adds up to the width of the DIV, and the size of the left element is equals to the size of the right element.

Any nice way to do this ?

EDIT:

I figured the only two ways were either using javascript or tables. I used tables and it worked fine.

```
div
{
    display: table;
}

#111, #222
{
    width: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: What is the ultimate goal of this? There may be a better approach to the problem.

Comment: Are the right and left elements a fixed size?

Comment: Unfortunately, they're not.

The ultimate goal is to have a centered text and some decoration on the left and right of it (the decorations are different) maybe some SVG rectangles or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to give the center element width:100%; and text-align:center;

Comment: What about the other elements ? They're not fixed size, they have to fill whatever remaining space there is.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps?

```
<div style="width:500px;border:1px solid #000;">

<span>1111</span>
<span style="text-align:center">dynamic text</span>

<span style="text-align:right; float:right;">2222</span>

</div>
```